# Second Array item gets removed

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm pulling data from CloudKit to put into an Array.

I have 3 items that can be pulled: `Monday`, `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`

I put them into an `existingArray`, but when I run the app I get: `["Monday", "Tuesday"]`, then as it runs thru a second time I get `["Monday", "Wednesday"]`, and I can't figure out why?

```
    for days in results! {
        let nD = DayClass()
        nD.dayOfTheWeek = days[“D”] as! String
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            if var existingArr = defaults.arrayForKey("D") as? [String] {
                if existingArr.contains(days["D"] as! String) == false {
                    existingArr.append(nd.dayOfTheWeek)
                }
            } else {
                defaults.setObject([nD.dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "D")
            }
        }
```

Edit: If I add `defaults.setObject([nD.dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "D")` after I append, `existingArray` becomes `["Monday", "Tuesday"]` then `["Tuesday", "Wednesday"]`. I can't get it to just keep all 3 items in the `existingArray`.

Comment: If `contains` passes, then you append an element to `existingArr`, but in the next iteration of the loop you just overwrite it again. As the code stands, it looks like you need to `setObject` after you `append`.

Comment: If I add `defaults.setObject([nD.dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "D")` after I `append`, then for some reason the array runs `["Monday", "Tuesday"]` then  `["Tuesday", "Wednesday"]`.  I can't get it to just keep all 3 items in the array somehow

Comment: You would have to save the whole array - `defaults.setObject(existingArr, forKey: "D")`.

Comment: Yup there we go! If you want to put that as an answer I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the `existingArr` back to defaults after you `append`. Along the lines of:

```
for days in results! {
    let nD = DayClass()
    nD.dayOfTheWeek = days[“D”] as! String
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        if var existingArr = defaults.arrayForKey("D") as? [String] {
            if existingArr.contains(days["D"] as! String) == false {
                existingArr.append(nd.dayOfTheWeek)
                defaults.setObject(existingArr, forKey: "D")
            }
        } else {
            defaults.setObject([nD.dayOfTheWeek], forKey: "D")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it